# How to ignore an html tag of a 3rd party component in an angular4 unit test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have looked in the docs, checked SO, and tried different solutions/work arounds and I just can't seem to get this to work. I am writing a unit test for an angular4 app with karma/jasmine. It tests a component which makes use of a third party component ckeditor (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ckeditor). Although when I run the test I get this error...

> Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>   'ckeditor' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'ckeditor' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("[ERROR ->]
>
> > "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/CkEditorComponent.html@0:0 Error: Template parse errors: 'ckeditor' is not a known element:
> >     1. If 'ckeditor' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> >     2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("[ERROR ->] "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/CkEditorComponent.html@0:0 ...

My unit test file looks like this

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ManageInvanareLoginComponent } from './manage-invanare-login.component';
import {CreateDriftInfoComponent} from "../create-drift-info/create-drift-info.component";
import {CreateLoginTextComponent} from "../create-login-text/create-login-text.component";
import {MdInputContainer, MdInputModule} from "@angular/material";
import {CKEditorModule} from "ng2-ckeditor";
import {CkEditorComponent} from "../ck-editor/ck-editor.component";

describe('ManageInvanareLoginComponent', () => {
  let component: ManageInvanareLoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ManageInvanareLoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        CkEditorComponent,
        CreateDriftInfoComponent,
        CreateLoginTextComponent,
        ManageInvanareLoginComponent,
        MdInputContainer
      ],
      providers:[
        CKEditorModule,
        MdInputModule
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ManageInvanareLoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

My app.module.ts file looks like this...

```
    ...
           import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core"; 
        import { CKEditorModule } from 'ng2-ckeditor';


            @NgModule({   declarations: [
                AppComponent,
                WelcomeComponent,
                DriftInfoDisplayComponent,
                LoginInfoComponent,
                SideBarComponent,
                CkEditorComponent,
                ManageInvanareLoginComponent,
                CreateDriftInfoComponent,
                CreateLoginTextComponent   ],   exports:[
                CkEditorComponent   ],   imports: [
                CKEditorModule,
                BrowserModule,
                FormsModule,
                HttpModule,
                AppRoutingModule,
                BrowserAnimationsModule,
                MdGridListModule,
                MdButtonModule,
                MdInputModule   ],   providers: [
                PathsService,
                DriftInfoDisplayComponent,
                DriftInfoService   
                ],   
            schemas:[NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],   
            bootstrap: [AppComponent] }) 
            export class AppModule { }
```

I dont event want to test the ckeditor element but I do want to test other functions in the component which contains this creditor element tag.

Is there a way that I can tell the test to just ignore this tag?

Comment: Can you share your test?

Comment: @yurzui just did! thanks.

Comment: Add `schemas:[NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]` to `TestBed.configureTestingModule`

Comment: Oh my gosh, I feel really silly, thanks, it works now.

Comment: If you want to add that as a solution, I can give you a nice green checkmark.

Comment: The sources that I read said to add this line in the app.module.ts, but I took that away and added it here instead, and it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should also add `schemas:[NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]` to your test configuration

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ...
  schemas:[NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
});
```

See also

- https://blog.nrwl.io/essential-angular-testing-192315f8be9b

Comment: don't forget to import the schema:
`import {NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';`